# Empty the input value with disabled input in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

What I want is to have the `input` disabled and emptied such that if **LEVEL2** input is empty then **LEVEL3** and **LEVEL4** should be disabled and have empty value.

And if **LEVEL3** input is empty then **LEVEL4** should be disabled and have empty value.

The disabled code is working, but the value is still there.  I already have something like this:

```
<el-form-item :prop="'materialInfo.' + e_key + '.LEVEL2'" :rules="level2Rules" class="u_f_left">
  <span>-</span>
  <el-input v-model="e_val.LEVEL2" :value="e_val.LEVEL2" placeholder="階層2" class="wid70" @blur="joinLevel(e_key)" clearable></el-input>
</el-form-item>
 <el-form-item :prop="'materialInfo.' + e_key + '.LEVEL3'" :rules="level3Rules" class="u_f_left">
  <span>-</span>
  <el-input :disabled="e_val.LEVEL2?false:true" v-model="e_val.LEVEL3" :value="e_val.LEVEL3" placeholder="階層3" class="wid70" @blur="joinLevel(e_key)" clearable></el-input>
</el-form-item>
<el-form-item :prop="'materialInfo.' + e_key + '.LEVEL4'" :rules="level4Rules" class="u_f_left">
  <span>-</span>
  <el-input :disabled="e_val.LEVEL3?false:true" v-model="e_val.LEVEL4" :value="e_val.LEVEL4" placeholder="階層4" class="wid70" @blur="joinLevel(e_key)" clearable></el-input>
</el-form-item>
```

It goes like this:
[image]

I removed the value of **LEVEL2**, so **LEVEL3** got disabled.  But **LEVEL4** is enabled since there's still value in **LEVEL3**.

So what can I do to remove the value of **LEVEL3,4,5** if LEVEL2 value is removed.

And **LEVEL4,5** removed, if **LEVEL3** is empty.
And **LEVEL5** removed, if **LEVEL4** is empty.

I tried putting conditions in `v-model` like this:

```
<el-input :disabled="e_val.LEVEL2?false:true" v-model="e_val.LEVEL2?e_val.LEVEL3:EMPTYVALUE" :value="e_val.LEVEL3" placeholder="階層3" class="wid70" @blur="joinLevel(e_key)" clearable></el-input>
```

`EMPTYVALUE` is declared as `EMPTYVALUE: '',`.

But seems like I get some errors and won't compile.

And also I'd like to avoid using the `blur` or `change events` if that's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:
add watch property on each input.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
      input: {
        one: "",
        two: "",
        three: "",
        four: ""
      }
  },
  watch: {
    input: {
      handler(val) {
        !val.one ? (this.input.two = "") : "";
        !val.two ? (this.input.three = "") : "";
        !val.three ? (this.input.four = "") : "";
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <input type="text" v-model="input.one" placeholder="one" />
    <input type="text" v-model="input.two" placeholder="two" :disabled="!input.one" />
    <input type="text" v-model="input.three" placeholder="three" :disabled="!input.two" />
    <input type="text" v-model="input.four" placeholder="four" :disabled="!input.three" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      boxes: new Array(5),
    }
  },
  computed: {
    lastBox() {
      let lastBox = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.boxes.length; i++) {
        if (this.boxes[i] && this.boxes[i].length && i == lastBox) {
          lastBox++;
        } else {
          this.boxes[i] = '';
        }
      }
      return lastBox;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 50px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-for="(item, index) in boxes" :key="index"
         v-model="boxes[index]" :disabled="index > lastBox" />
</div>
```